# Why wouldn't hook_form_submit be called?

Tags: 6, forms

```
function mymodule_reviewer_node_form($node, &$form_state) {
global $school;
if ($school) {
    $form['field_reviewer_school']['#value'] = array(array('nid' => $school));
    $form['field_reviewer_school']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
  return $form;
}

function mymodule_reviewer_node_form_submit($node, &$form_state) {
}
```

The form gets submitted successfully, but form_submit never gets called. What might cause this?

Comment: May you show more of the first function?

Comment: Are you sure you selected the right tag for the Drupal version? A form builder function doesn't receive the `$form` parameter, in Drupal 6.

Comment: Added the code that's in the first function. Pretty dull stuff. It's definitely D6 and according to this: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--node.php/function/hook_form/6 hook_form in d6 takes and returns a $form object.

Comment: Actually, `hook_form()` is invoked as `hook_form(&$node, $form_state)`; the first parameter is not a form array, but the node being edited.

Comment: Yeah but what I call it doesn't really matter. :P

Comment: Well, it does matter for who answers, as needs to understand to what you are referring to. Until you didn't said you were referring to the implementation of `hook_form()`, I was wondering if the functions were a form builder, and a form submission handler.

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: One last question: What is the short name of the module, "mymodule_reviewer_node" or "mymodule_reviewer"?

Comment: mymodule is the name of the module. Reviewer is the name of the content type which I'm trying to work with. Judging by the course your questions are taking I'm guessing I have a big misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: I am looking to what Drupal core modules do; for example, poll.module has `poll_form()` (the implementation of `hook_form()`), and `poll_node_form_submit()` (the submission handler). I still have to find out if that is how the submission handler must be named, and which code decides that.

Answer (score 1):

The form should be:

```
   function  mymod_reviewer_node_form($form_state) {
     $form = array();

     // Build the form...

     return $form;
   }
```

The submit handler should be:

```
   function mymod_reviewer_node_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
     // Do something with $form_state['values'] or whatever
   }
```

And make sure that whatever is rendering the form passes through `drupal_get_form()`.

Finally, one tricky bit: Make sure you are not accidentally overriding a hook. `mymod_form()`, for example, implements `hook_form()`, which is probably not what you really intend to do.

I find that nine times out of ten, if the submit handler is not being called, it's because I named the function incorrectly.

Comment: I notice you left out the $node parameter in your first function. I'm trying to simply alter the form with my first function (which seems to be working), not build it from scratch.

Comment: Joren is implementing `hook_form()`, not a form builder. The first argument of that hook is `&$node`.